# Best practice in programmatically creating UI

Tags: android, mobile, view

lately i always got to a point where i want to create my UI dynamically.
I found a way to do so but i dont really like it.

For example i wanted to create a GoogleCalender like Dayview and ended up doing like so: (don't read the code in detail just see that it's bad)

```
constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();

        View nextHolder = new View(this);
        View nextMarker = new View(this);
        TextView nextTime = new TextView(this);

        holders[i] = nextHolder;
        times[i] = nextTime;
        markers[i] = nextMarker;

        int calcHour = hour + i;

        if (calcHour < 10) {
            nextTime.setText("0" + Integer.toString(calcHour) + ":00");
        } else {
            nextTime.setText(Integer.toString(calcHour) + ":00");
        }
        nextTime.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
        nextMarker.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.grey, null));

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            holders[i].setId(Utils.generateViewId());
            markers[i].setId(Utils.generateViewId());
            times[i].setId(Utils.generateViewId());
        } else {
            holders[i].setId(View.generateViewId());
            markers[i].setId(View.generateViewId());
            times[i].setId(View.generateViewId());
        }

        int nextHolderID = holders[i].getId();
        int nextMarkerID = markers[i].getId();
        int nextTimeID = nextTime.getId();

        constraintLayout.addView(holders[i]);
        constraintLayout.addView(markers[i]);
        constraintLayout.addView(times[i]);

        constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);

        //Constraint the Time-Stamp-Holders
        constraintSet.constrainHeight(nextHolderID, Utils.convertDpToPixel(40, context));
        constraintSet.constrainWidth(nextHolderID, ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);
        constraintSet.connect(nextHolderID, ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                ConstraintSet.START);
        constraintSet.connect(nextHolderID, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,
                ConstraintSet.END);
        if (i == 1) {
            constraintSet.connect(nextHolderID, ConstraintSet.TOP, startHolder.getId(),
                    ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, Utils.convertDpToPixel(8, context));
        } else {
            constraintSet.connect(nextHolderID, ConstraintSet.TOP, holders[i - 1].getId(),
                    ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, Utils.convertDpToPixel(8, context));
        }

        //Constraint the Time TextViews
        constraintSet.constrainHeight(nextTimeID, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
        constraintSet.constrainWidth(nextTimeID, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
        constraintSet.connect(nextTimeID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, nextHolderID,
                ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, Utils.convertDpToPixel(8, context));
        constraintSet.connect(nextTimeID, ConstraintSet.TOP, nextHolderID,
                ConstraintSet.TOP, Utils.convertDpToPixel(8, context));
        constraintSet.connect(nextTimeID, ConstraintSet.START, nextHolderID,
                ConstraintSet.START, Utils.convertDpToPixel(16, context));

        //Constraint the timeline Views
        constraintSet.constrainHeight(nextMarkerID, ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);
        constraintSet.constrainWidth(nextMarkerID, ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);

        constraintSet.connect(nextMarkerID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, nextTimeID,
                ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, Utils.convertDpToPixel(8, context));
        constraintSet.connect(nextMarkerID, ConstraintSet.TOP, nextTimeID,
                ConstraintSet.TOP, Utils.convertDpToPixel(8, context));
        constraintSet.connect(nextMarkerID, ConstraintSet.START, nextTimeID,
                ConstraintSet.END, Utils.convertDpToPixel(16, context));
        constraintSet.connect(nextMarkerID, ConstraintSet.END, nextHolderID,
                ConstraintSet.END, Utils.convertDpToPixel(16, context));

        constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

It's ugly and not performant.

So what i want to create now is a match history:

[image]

I would have a view that holds a match with 2 textViews for each teamname and 1 textView for the score. Those arrows should show how they would be placed in a constraint layout.

My guess how it should be done would be to create a layout.xml for the MatchView and in that xml i have a placeholder for the other textViews which i than can change programmatically. This layout.xml would be then used by my MatchView class and an object of my MatchView class is one MatchView.

For example:

```
MatchView matchView = new MatchView("Team1", "Team2", "score")
```

And the MatchView class would look like this:

```
public class MatchView {

MatchView.setLayout(match_view.xml);

TextView team1 = findViewById(team1TXT);
TextView team2 ...

//For the first view
MatchView(String team1, String team2, String score){
    team1.setText(team1);
    //...
    constrain.toParent();
}

//For every following view
MatchView(String team1, String team2, String score, MatchView parentMatchView){
    team1.setText(team1);
    //...
    constrain.toView(parentMatchView);
    }
}
```

Is this the way how it's done? Are there more convenient ways?
If i guessed write do you have me a tutorial where they show how you really do it?
I searched for many days but i don't find what im really looking for.
I hope I'm not asking something too stupid.

Thanks in advance and greetings

Bolle

Comment: simply create one horizontal `LinearLayout` with 3 `TextView`s inside in some xml layout file and use `LayoutInflater` to create it at runtime and add to some master container (most likely `ListView` / `RecyclerView` / vertical `LinearLayout`)

Comment: I will give it a try. You will hear from me. Thanks for the food for thought!

Comment: Got i working with the RecyclerView. Thanks